# How can I use a singleton class in AOP (aspect oriented programming)?

Tags: class, singleton, aop, aspectj

Language by choice is AspectJ but I am open for a generic answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.christianschenk.org/blog/singletons-with-aspectj/

The above link provides a small tutorial on using singletons within AspectJ.